# What are the most useful programming languages for computational linguists?

Tags: computational-linguistics

What programming languages should aspiring computational linguists learn?  Why?

Thanks!

Comment: Depends what you wanna do, really. But I'd say Python, only because I see it used a lot.

Comment: Welcome to Linguistics.SE! "Should" sounds like a subjective thing. People invite various tools specifically because they have different opinions about what "should" be used. Consider rewriting your question by defining your specific needs, then the question may get an objective answer.

Comment: There is no need to rewrite my question like you suggest because it is a technical and not a philosophical question. Additionally, since I am clearly new to computational linguistics (hence your "Welcome to Linguistics.SE!"), my post asks a very simple and valid question about the field. For example, programmers who want to design websites must/"should" know certain programming languages, while app developers "should" know others in order to succeed in their respective fields.

Comment: Why the downvotes?

Comment: It's too subjective and, more importantly IMO, far too broad. There are different kinds of computational linguistics, and I doubt someone doing MT at Google has the same needs as a distributional typologist.

Comment: Re subjective, no morse so than many other questions.  We all know it's not .NET.  Edit it to be acceptable.  Re broad, We have plenty of answers here of the form "if x, ... else ...", or with frequencies from a corpus (eg GitHub, arxiv, ACL workshop submissions...), over time, and/or sliced by some other variables (eg by subfields like MT).

Comment: @A.M you have *completely* changed what the question is asking, that is not a legitimate edit! And you've also invalidated your own answer at the same time. Amazing!

Comment: @curiousdannii I am not stopping you from editing it constructively.

Comment: @Am the most constructive course of action would be to leave the question how it was originally so that the OP can learn what kinds of questions can and can't work in the SE format.

Comment: **Mod notice:** I have rolled back to the second revision, which I think still had the same intent of the first version. In my personal opinion, as is the question can still be salvaged. It's not that bad but it can definitely be improved. Any suggestions are welcome.

Comment: @艾锐心 You can ask in our Meta for help in improving your own question. Don't consider it lost yet, with some improvements (even minor because I don't think it's that bad), it can be reopened. My personal suggestion is to make it as objective as you can. Also addressing the broadness would be a good idea. :)

Comment: This is the most totally and completely pathetic thing I have ever seen. Someone SERIOUSLY edited my question? It is for all intents and purposes exactly how I originally wrote it. AND my question is ON HOLD?! I want nothing to do with people who are petty and small enough to complain about my very legitimate question. An explanation of the fact that my question "asks the wrong question" would be enough, but I can't believe you all have enough time and audacity to put my question on hold. If computational linguistics is comprised of people like y'all, it's clearly not the right field for me.

Comment: In every site on the network "what is best?" questions aren't allowed. Questions on this site need to be able to be answered objectively. What is the most common would be acceptable. What is the most accessible to non-programmers would probably be okay, especially if it focused on the strength of stuff like tutorials and documentation. What tools are focused on specific tasks would be good too (computational linguistics is a huge field!) Do any of those questions work for you?

Comment: @艾锐心 People are editing your question to try to make it something that can be answered in the StackExchange fashion. They're trying to get you an answer that can be useful going forward. If you want to delete it and try again, I would suggest you pick three to five languages that you think are commonly used in comp ling and ask something like "what are the relative strengths and weaknesses of these languages in computational linguistics?". I suspect that would get you plenty of what you really want, which is a basis for deciding what you should work on next.

Comment: @艾锐心 I agree with you that this is not a philosophical question, but purely technical. I think that the part stating "most useful" makes the question subjective for some. Something like "Which programming languages are useful for computational linguistics" cannot be contested by any means. If you consider asking the question in a similar manner, I will stand by you side for reopening.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Python and C++**

In the old days, C/C++ was the language of Moses, Giza etc, and the language of the research pipelines and production infrastructure at Google (and I assume Microsoft) for search, translation, speech recognition, handwriting recognition and so on.  fastText is in C++.

Today, the Python ecosystem now has more to offer, both in natural language processing and in machine learning in general, and in serving infra.  Dealing with strings is just easier in Python, especially in Python 3.

Most of the major Python libs use Cython, so the implementers know C++, although the consumers need not.

Stanford NLP uses Java.

My approach for answering this pseudo-objectively would be to count the number of libraries or commits with certain keywords in GitHub, questions on SE and so on.

For example, if we search Google Scholar for *"NLP" OR "computational linguistics" OR "natural language processing" x*:

C++: 705 (2017: 16)
Python: 19,900 (2017: 2,640)
Java: 35,900 (2017: 2,310)

Choosing research papers over lines of code or other metrics is subjective, there are also some idiosyncrasies because these names could refer to other concepts or have synonyms like *C*.  And it will depend which subfield, which company, which region and so on.

That said, it is as important to know technologies and resources as languages.  For example, Unicode, ISO codes, file formats, distributed computing, TensorFlow seq2seq, containerisation, AWS, GitHub, StackExchange...

Comment: You really shouldn't be answering questions which so blatantly don't meet the site's standards...

Comment: @curiousdannii With all respect, all of you experienced users should spend your commenting effort fixing the basically good question of a new user so that it meets the site's standards.

Comment: @curiousdannii ^As I stated above, totally and completely pathetic.

Comment: I don't understand why you would answer with a single language. Multilingualism is mandatory.

Comment: @user6726 You're probably right.

Comment: The question is legit (though too broad). Python is a good choice for glue code, it's simple, everywhere and has lots of general and NLP libraries. For symbolic computation, Prolog is what many use because it's declarative and powerful. Of course, if you need something fast for number crunching, C++ is the best way to go.

Comment: I like your approach of answering this question. I work with those stuff and although statistically python and C++ seem to have a lot of commitment, I don't know if I would recommend them to an aspiring computational linguist. C++ can be very hard for people who want to get started and put their effort on the main task. Python is easy with a good base, but still. I recently had to port some C code of a dynamic programming algorithm and my final choise was between Java and C# (I picked it in the end). They are both relatively easy, well defined and way faster than python when it really matters.

Comment: Having said the above, that is just my opinion based on the requirements I had: ease of use/productivity and performance. R is another modern language that is not as big as Python in computational linguistics, but it will definetely be in the future. Any language with good AI libraries (Tensorflow, Accord etc) will get a bigger share within the computational linguistics community in the future.

Comment: @A.M.Bittlingmayer The stats in your content favor Java considerably over C++. Yet you title this with "Python and C++". Can you give any justification for choosing C++ over Java (which you seem to have done in the opposite direction)?

Comment: @Mitch Yes, contradiction.  I assume you agree that C++ is important and it's the statistic that is flawed?  (eg FastText is written in C++, C++ is used under the hood in top libs like spaCy, and ML libs like TensorFlow and Torch, but it's always upstream.)

Comment: @A.M.Bittlingmayer Before your post, I would have put Python way ahead at first and C/C++ and Java tied for second way behind. The difference between C++ and Java in your stats is so large that I am convinced that Java is way more useful. WHy do you think those stats are flawed? Once you have numbers you have to give a reasonable explanation of why they might be wrong.

Comment: Well, as I said, C/C++ is at the core of most of the top libraries today, and was the also the language of much of the previous generation of language model and translation code, and stuff like the Google internal stacks for search, translation and so on.  So, with the exception of Stanford NLP, top people on top projects write a lot of C/C++, and nil Java.  That may not yield more lines of code or even research paper mentions written worldwide, because those do not have much of a filter.