# Are there any computational linguists who still use prolog?

Tags: computational-linguistics, logic

My understanding is that in the 90's and early 2000's, expert systems and logical rules dominated the field of natural language processing/computational linguistics, but that for the last 10 years, researchers have increasingly turned to neural/statistical methods.  Is there any significant research still being done in using logic programming languages for real nlp/nlg systems?

Comment: Essentially nil.  I would say closer to 20 years in most respectable institutions.  See https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/24400/what-are-the-most-useful-programming-languages-for-computational-linguists/24401#24401